# Crear una modelo de base de datos que muestre los amigos de un usuario

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Buenas noches tengo un problema, estoy creando una base de datos la cual utiliza usuarios que a su vez tienen amigos, logro hacer mostrar la relación entre los usuarios y sus amigos pero no logro mostrar los nombres de los amigos (Solo logro mostrar ID)

Tabla usuarios:

```
CREATE TABLE usuario
(
 idUser serial NOT NULL,
 nombre TEXT,
 apellidoP TEXT,
 apellidoM TEXT,
 usuario TEXT,
 clave TEXT
);
ALTER TABLE usuario ADD CONSTRAINT PK_User PRIMARY KEY(idUser); 
INSERT INTO usuario (nombre,apellidoP,apellidoM,usuario, clave) VALUES ('Moises','Arias','Urbieta','dre0x', CRYPT('123456', GEN_SALT('md5')));
INSERT INTO usuario (nombre,apellidoP,apellidoM,usuario, clave) VALUES ('Marbella','Ramirez','de la Cruz','marbe', CRYPT('11112222', GEN_SALT('md5')));
INSERT INTO usuario (nombre,apellidoP,apellidoM,usuario, clave) VALUES ('Noel','Vazquez','Gomez','NoTrollOne', CRYPT('1111111', GEN_SALT('md5')));
```

Tabla de amigos:

```
CREATE TABLE friendlist (               
idUser INTEGER,             
idUser_FK INTEGER               
)               

ALTER TABLE friendlist ADD CONSTRAINT FK_User_Friends FOREIGN KEY (idUser) REFERENCES usuario(idUser);              
ALTER TABLE friendlist ADD CONSTRAINT FK_User_FK_Friends FOREIGN KEY (idUser_FK) REFERENCES usuario(idUser);                

INSERT INTO friendlist VALUES(1,2); 
INSERT INTO friendlist VALUES(1,3);
```

Usando este código me muestra lo siguiente:

```
SELECT A.idUser, A.nombre, B.idUser_FK  FROM usuario A INNER JOIN friendlist B ON A.idUser = B.idUser;

iduser | nombre | iduser_fk
--------+--------+-----------
      1 | Moises |         2
      1 | Moises |         3
(2 filas)
```

Me gustaría mostrar los nombres de las personas que son amigos de "Moises" pero no logro hacerlo. Espero puedan ayudarme

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que hacer otro `JOIN`con la tabla `user` reclamando la relación de amistad.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT A1.idUser, A1.nombre, A2.idUser id_amigo, 
       A2.nombre nombre_amigo, B.idUser_FK  FROM usuario A1 
       INNER JOIN friendlist B ON A1.idUser = B.idUser
       INNER JOIN usuario A2 ON B.idUser_FK = A2.idUser;
```

O bien, para que quede más claro:

```
SELECT 

    A1.idUser, A1.nombre, 
    A2.idUser id_amigo, A2.nombre nombre_amigo, 

    B.idUser_FK  

    FROM friendlist B

    INNER JOIN usuario A1  ON A1.idUser = B.idUser
    INNER JOIN usuario A2 ON B.idUser_FK = A2.idUser;
```

*El resultado será siempre el mismo*

**Resultado**

```
    iduser  nombre  id_amigo    nombre_amigo    iduser_fk
1   1       Moises  2           Marbella         2
2   1       Moises  3           Noel             3
```

---

O bien, en una sola fila los amigos del usuario `x`, usando funciones de agregación (Postgresql), en MySQL sería más fácil con GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT 

    A1.idUser, A1.nombre, 
    array_to_string(array_agg (A2.idUser), ', ') id_amigos, 
    array_to_string(array_agg (A2.nombre), ', ') nombre_amigos

    FROM friendlist B

    INNER JOIN usuario A1  ON A1.idUser = B.idUser
    INNER JOIN usuario A2 ON B.idUser_FK = A2.idUser

    GROUP BY A1.idUser;
```

**Resultado**

```
    iduser    nombre    id_amigos      nombre_amigos
1   1         Moises    2, 3           Marbella, Noel
```

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar tu tabla `friendlist` no es consistente ya que se puede insertar la misma amistad varias veces. Para solucionarlo debes añadir una clave primaria. También debes tratar de definir la clave foránea durante la creación de la tabla. A continuación te dejo lo dicho para las dos tablas:

En la tabla usuario puedes quitar el `NOT NULL` de `idUser` ya que un `PRIMARY KEY` implica que no puede ser `NULL`.

```
CREATE TABLE usuario
(
     idUser serial PRIMARY KEY,
     nombre TEXT,
     apellidoP TEXT,
     apellidoM TEXT,
     usuario TEXT,
     clave TEXT
);
```

La tabla de amistades debe referenciar con ambos campos al campo `idUser` de la tabla de usuarios. Y formamos una `PRIMARY KEY` compuesta (cuando es de un sólo campo puede ir en la misma línea que defines el campo como he hecho en la anterior tabla).

```
CREATE TABLE friendlist (               
    idUser INTEGER REFERENCES usuario(idUser),             
    idUser_FK INTEGER REFERENCES usuario(idUser),
    PRIMARY KEY(idUser, idUser_FK)
);
```

Si ejecutas los `INSERT INTO` que tenías para en `friendlist` verás que siguen funcionando, pero si tratas de insertar los datos repetidos dará un error. Eso permite que cada relación de amistad sea única y que por ejemplo, no tengas repetida la relación de amistad entre Moisés y Marbella (con tu código anterior sí que se podía).

En lo referente a tú consulta:

Lo que estás haciendo es obtener los amigos de Moisés pero en la tabla `friendlist`, y lo único que aparece en esa tabla es su `idUser_FK`, que al fin y al cabo es un número representativo pero no nos aporta mucha información.

La solución es realizar otro JOIN del resultado con la tabla `usuario`. De esa forma puedes obtener el nombre del amigo sabiendo su `iduser_FK` obtenido de la tabla `friendlist`.

Antes de ver las consultas resumimos todo esto.

1. A partir de tu tabla `usuario` obtienes las filas de `friendlist`que tienen como `idUser` el id de Moisés (vamos, que estás buscando a los amigos de Moisés). Llegados a este punto sabemos los `idUser_FK` de los amigos de Moisés.
2. Esos `idUser_FK` obtenidos de la tabla `friendlist` debemos volver a buscarlos en la tabla `usuario`. Se podría decir que estás buscando en la tabla `usuario` el `idUser` que sea equivalente al `idUser_FK` de los amigos de Moisés.

Paso a paso:

1.Buscamos en la tabla de amistades (friendlist) los id de los amigos de Moisés:

```
SELECT lista.iduser_fk FROM 
usuario usuario INNER JOIN friendlist lista ON    
usuario.iduser=lista.iduser WHERE usuario.nombre='Moises';
```

Obteniendo el resultado:

```
iduser_fk 
-----------
     2
     3
```

2.Ahora debemos buscar esos id en la tabla de usuarios, modificando la consulta con un `INNER JOIN` con la tabla `usuario`:

```
SELECT amigo.nombre FROM 
usuario AS usuario INNER JOIN friendlist AS lista ON usuario.iduser=lista.iduser 
INNER JOIN usuario AS amigo ON amigo.iduser=lista.iduser_fk
WHERE usuario.nombre='Moises';
```

El resultado es:

```
  nombre  
----------
 Marbella
 Noel
```

Además debes poner la cláusula `WHERE` del resultado que te he mostrado porque sino no filtrará por el nombre Moisés, en este aunque no pongas `WHERE` va a salir el mismo resultado porque sólo tienes amigos para Moisés. pero si pruebas a añadir otra relación de amistad entre dos personas que no sean Moisés, también te la mostrará.

Para comprobar lo que te digo, inserta esta nueva amistad entre Marbella y Noel:

```
INSERT INTO friendlist VALUES(2,3);
```

Si realizas la consulta sin la cláusula `WHERE`del final te muestra Noel dos veces, porque Noel es amigo de Marbella y de Moisés:

```
SELECT amigo.nombre FROM 
usuario AS usuario INNER JOIN friendlist AS lista ON     
usuario.iduser=lista.iduser 
INNER JOIN usuario AS amigo ON amigo.iduser=lista.iduser_fk;

  nombre  
----------
 Marbella
 Noel
 Noel
```

Espero que te sirva, si tienes alguna duda no dudes en mandar mensaje :)